# how to link a c++ object to a local variable in Lua

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

I'm completing my scripting interface with Lua, but recently I've stuck at some point. I have several functions for my `Entitiy` events like `Update()`. I have a function called `create_entitiy()` which instantiate a new entity from a given entity index:

```
function Update()
  local bullet = create_entity(0, 0, "obj_bullet")
end
```

`create_entity` returns a table which is the properties of the created entity. Now how can I make a connection between `bullet` variable and my newly created object?

Right now for previously added objects to the scene, I simply set a global table for each of them and then after every call to `Update()`, I go through registered names to find object tables and perform new changes. Like the one below:

```
function Update()
  if keyboard_key_press(vk_right) then obj_player.x += 3
end
```

I can get `obj_player` table because I know its name from C++, plus I can get it as a global table and simply reach for the first instance named `obj_player`.

Is there any solution for me to make `bullet` variable act like this?

I was thinking to get all `local` variables in `Update()` function and check for every one to see if is it table and it has an unique field attached to it like `id`, this way I can determine that this is an object table and do the rest of the process.

By the way, is this interface going to work easier with `luaBind` if I implement it?

**Bottom line:**

How can I make a local variable in Lua that receives a table from `create_entity` function and track that local variable to capture it from C++.

e. g.

```
function Update()
  local bullet = create_entity(0, 0, "obj_bullet")
  bullet.x = 10 <== Commit a change in table
end
```

Now I want to get variable `bullet` from C++. And it's not just this variable, there might be a ton of these local variables with different names.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Locals in Lua _reference_ tables, not copy them.  If you modify the value of a table like position in C++ then that value is automatically visible Lua.  You only need to change variables values in Lua if you're setting primitive value types (numbers, booleans, etc.) or you're changing references.

Comment: See last part I've added.

Comment: You want to make it so that when you change the value of a local variable (not a value inside a table), C++ picks up on it?  Or make it so that when you change a value inside a table, C++ gets a callback letting it know?  Your example code indicates you're modifying a value in a table but your question update indicates you just want to change the value of a local variable - these are not the same things.

Comment: The one that is changing a table's field is my normal modifying of global registered tables from C++. They're my added objects to the scene and not run-time instantiated. The one with local variable receives a table returned from `create_entity`. I want to track that local variable and capture it from C++ in order to extract its contents which is a table and do my job with that data... I know how to pass and get tables but I don't know how to track local variables. They can be hundreds.

Comment: I am not sure enough what you are asking to try to draw up an answer. But if I understand correctly, you would like to be able to "create" an object in Lua and then get a hold of them C++-side.
Thinking from a bullet perspective, you may want to create a pool of bullet objects C++ side, and create an API for "getting" a bullet object within Lua. You can then set it as active or something and change whatever data you want to. Then the C++ side could act on this in whatever way you wanted to. But in the end, C++ would be managing the lifetime of the Bullet object. Lua would simply input data.

Comment: Also I am not sure what `By the way, is this interface going to work easier with luaBind if I implement it?` means. Did you mean to have a 'than' in between luaBind and if? If so, then yes, using a binding library would make exposing objects back and fourth easier than doing all the stack work yourself. Personally I never got LuaBind to work, and ended up using the Squirrel scripting language and the Sqrat binding library instead. (Very similar to a Lua setup, but with native object support)

Comment: The `create_entity` function is implemented in C++, isn't it?  Can't you just add any entities the Lua code creates to a global list in C++?

Comment: @DeanKnight, I'm not sure that you've got my point, but the Squirrel thing does worth a try I think. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanReed, That's the point. I'm making new instances in my C++ entities list, but I have to control them too. Right now I have to set a handle for my newly created object which in this case I return a Lua table including a unique id field for that instance as result of `create_entity`. Now `local bullet` would get a table as its value, after that I don't how to get that `local bullet` variable from C++ to detect changes in its value (the recently returned table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sean Middleditch said in the comments, locals in Lua *reference* tables, not copy them.  Therefore if you have some code like

```
local bullet = create_entity(0, 0, "obj_bullet")
bullet.x = 10    -- Commit a change in table
```

what you really need to keep track of is *not* the local variable `bullet`, but rather the table returned by `create_entity`.  There can be any number of local variables, fields, etc. that reference this same entity, but (as far as I understand your question) you don't need to keep track of all of them, only the single table they refer to.

So all you need to do is, in the implementation of `create_entity`, store a reference to the created table someplace where you can retrieve it later.  For instance, you might have a global table of all entities, keyed by the entity's ID, and reference the entity table from there.  You could then find this table from C++ (since its name is fixed) and walk over its entries whenever you needed to check for updates.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I didn't pay attention to `locals in Lua reference tables, not copy them.`